# Idiomatic way to deal with Repetitive Case Classes

Tags: scala, object, functional-programming, abstraction, case-class

I am learning about case classes. From what I understand case classes cannot be extended by other cases classes. What is the idiomatic way to deal with the following issue:

I have two cases classes, A and B. They are identical and feed into another case Class C. Now the issue arises when I want to define a "+" function. This can be seen below:

```
object Example extends App {
  // repetitive case classes A and B - Can they be abstracted to one case class?
  case class A(a: Int, b: String) {
    def f1(): Unit = println(a, b)
  }
  case class B(a: Int, b: String) {
    def f1(): Unit = println(a, b)
  }

  case class C(a: A, b: B) {
    def serialize() = Map("a" -> a, "b" -> b)
    def +(new_a: A): C = C(new_a, b)
    def +(new_b: B): C = C(a, new_b)
  }
}
```

The above compiles, but is very repetetive. If I remove case class B, and just use case class A, I can try and do something like this:

```
// if I use the same type for both A and B, I cannot use + individually anymore
case class C_alt(a: A, b: A) {
  def serialize() = Map("a" -> a, "b" -> b)
  def +(new_a: A): C_alt = C_alt(new_a, b)
  def +(new_b: A): C_alt = C_alt(a, new_b)
}
```

However, I can now no longer have both the "+" function for A and B, since the types are the same and overloading fails.

What is the idiomatic scala way to solve this code repetition problem? Ideally I would like to have a common case class implementing the methods, and A and B both extend it. But since case class extension by another case class is not allowed, should I use a normal class?

Comment: Should you use a normal class? That depends on why you're using `case` classes in the first place. Which of the handful of convenience features make `case` classes attractive for your application? Most, if not all, of them can be coded in to a normal class.

Comment: If you want different types, you need different types. That is not a problem of case classes, with normal classes you would have the same problem. What about using proper method names instead of `+` like `setA` and `setB`

Comment: Thanks folks, the main reason I am using case classes is because they serialize pretty easily with libraries like circe. I was using "+" as a function as I am just updating fields in a case class, which is really just a json object after it is serialized. I guess I can use setA and setB too which avoids this whole issue

Comment: BTW, you may want to use the `copy` method.

Comment: thanks @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez - that looks pretty useful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you can use normal `class`, as suggested by everyone. And you can use `copy` (which is provided for case classes) instead of your `+` methods.

But, if you want to get the free `case class` functions and you have multiple common behaviors then you can use `trait` to abstract out the behaviour for your types.

```scala
trait TDemo {
  def i: Int

  def s: String

  def f1(): Unit = println(i, s)

  def f2(): Int = i + 10

  def f3(): String = s + " LOL"

  def toString: String
}

case class Demo1(a: Int, b: String) extends TDemo
case class Demo2(a: Int, b: String) extends TDemo

trait TDemoWrapper[A <: TDemo, B <: TDemo] {
  def a: A

  def b: B

  def serialize() = Map("a" -> a, "b" -> b)
  
  def f1(): Unit = println(s"a :: $a, b :: $b")
}

case class DemoWrapper1(a: Demo1, b: Demo2) extends TDemoWrapper[Demo1, Demo2]
case class DemoWrapper2(a: Demo1, b: Demo1) extends TDemoWrapper[Demo1, Demo1]
```